# How to setup infinispan cache in a two node cluster

Tags: caching, infinispan

I need to setup Infinispan (In Memory Cache) in two node Cluster. Any basic level setup documentation for the same would be appreciable. The documentation found in Internet is so vague and doesn't suit a beginner. I've developed an application which caches the data from csv in eclipse. But when i deploy the jar in two nodes, it does the same and how am i supposed to find out whether the cache is distributed.? Any step by step guide to deploy an application which supports distributed caching.

Thanks,
Ajith Kumar

Comment: I'm trying to install the cluster manually and i don't want a programmatic approach. It would be helpful if some 1 could let me know what are the files and corresponding parameters to be edited before starting the inifinispan server. I have two servers and i'm trying to start infinispan 7.0 with the clustered.sh script as told in the documentation and trying to create a cache from command line after running ispn.sh script. But the cache doesn't seem to be distributed.

Answer (score 1):

The cache is not distributed by default, you have to configure it.

I suggest looking at the [clustered cache quickstart](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/blob/master/clustered-cache/src/main/java/org/infinispan/quickstart/clusteredcache/Node.java).

Comment: Hi Dan, many thanks for your reply. but i'm trying to use infinispan server 7.0 and i am unable to find infinispan.xml file in the  zip. can you let me know how to use the same setup on 7.0 version.

Comment: The infinispan.xml file is here: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/blob/master/clustered-cache/src/main/resources/infinispan.xml